# Error with IIS 7: Application pool has been automatically disabled

Tags: iis-7, application-pools

I have a web application running on Windows 2008 R2 Service Pack 1. From time to time ApplicationPool becomes disabled and I have to restart it manually. The time between crash and restart is critical.

In the Event Log I see 5 warnings and 1 error.

> **WARNING 1:** *A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process
>   Activation Service. The process id was '4028'. The data field contains
>   the error number.*
>
> **WARNING 2:** *A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process
>   Activation Service. The process id was '6400'. The data field contains
>   the error number.*
>
> **WARNING 3:** *A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process
>   Activation Service. The process id was '27892'. The data field
>   contains the error number.*
>
> **WARNING 4:** *A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process
>   Activation Service. The process id was '30180'. The data field
>   contains the error number.*
>
> **WARNING 5:** *A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process
>   Activation Service. The process id was '14816'. The data field
>   contains the error number.*
>
> **ERROR:** *Application pool 'MyAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that
>   application pool.*

Do you happen to know what is the issue? What should I do in order to fix it?

Comment: The answers on this SO question offer a few reasons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204444/iis7-a-process-serving-application-pool-yyyyy-suffered-a-fatal-communication

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010807/application-pool-defaultapppool-is-being-automatically-disabled-due-to-a-serie) stackoverflow answer:

> IIS comes with a feature called Rapid-Fail Protection. By default an
>   App Pool is configured to become disabled if a worker in the pool
>   crashes 5 times within a 5 minute span.
>
> The thresholds of this setting are able to be modified by right
>   clicking on the App Pool going to Advanced Settings and modifying the
>   'Rapid-Fail Protection' properties. However, this event indicates that
>   there is likely a serious issue in your application that needs to be
>   resolved.